# 2x2 contingency table - maximum likelihood estimate of the odds ratio and exact confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, contingency-tables

I have two questions regarding the following 2x2 contingency table:

[image]

1, How can I derive the maximum likelihood estimate of the odds ratio ($OR = (a*d)/(c*b)$)

2, How can I derive exact confidence intervals (not wald normal approximations)

It is my understanding that a distributional assumption must be made, i would have thought this would be binomial, but am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Not sure about a maximum likelihood estimate, but have a look at the epi.tests() function in the epiR package in R. If you're not using R, then perhaps at least the documentation might point you in the right direction because it has references for each statistic. The documentation doesn't explicitly mention confidence intervals for the odds ratio, but it does calculate the confidence interval (I checked).